# issues with Calling watson API from a .net framework project. .net framework cannot refer to a .net core project

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version, watson-conversation

I have a project that targets .NET framework 4.6 and I need to call Watson Conversation API there. I created a .NET core project and added the IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud NuGET packages, however it doesn't allow me to refer to .net core app from a .net framework.

> Error: project X targets .NETCoreApp, Version=v1.1. it cannot be referenced by a project that targets .NETFramework, Version=v4.6

I tried so many things but it still doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or .NET Platform 4.x?

Comment: I'm using .NET core. I just edited the .csproj file and changed the framework manually to net45 and seems it's working now!

Answer (score 4):

Ameneh Sh.

The [IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.*](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk) are in version 1.3 of the .net standard library, which only supports version 4.6 of the .Net Framework

I would still like to understand your scenario. I understand that you have two projects one .Net Framework 4.5 and another .Net Core. But the .Net Core Project is an App or a Classlibrary? Please let me know more details about your scenario.

Comment: I changed the target framework to 4.6 but I still get the error that a .net core v1.1 cannot be referenced by a project that targets .NETframework v4.6. When I create a .net core project and manually change the target framework to n3t46 in .csproj file, it seems working.